# Is there difference between these two expressions?

Tags: c, embedded, constants

Since my compiler gives different statistics for these two pieces of code, I am wondering what makes them different, if at all?

First one:

```
typedef const struct process_data
{
   uint8_t *name;
   void (*p_func)(void);
} process_data_t;

process_data_t processes = {15,16};
```

And the second one is:

```
typedef struct process_data
{
   uint8_t *name;
   void (*p_func)(void);
} process_data_t;

const process_data_t processes = {15,16};
```

Note that `const` qualifier has moved from typedefing to the definition of the structure. For me there is no difference between the two excerpts, but the compiler/linker statistic shows that less flash memory (the platform is a microcontroller with constrained resources) is consumed when the second piece of code is used.

Comment: Look at the differences in the `map` file. And report back :)

Comment: please provide a more complete example, just enough to show the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some amount of freedom that the compiler can take in interpreting these declarations, but, in general, here is the difference:

- The `typedef` "says": this is a type that is always `const`, meaning there is no "legal" way to take away the `const`-nes of *any* variable of this type. Whenever you pass data of this type or pointers to it, they will be const. Sure, casting "works", but only to another type, and may lead to Undefined Behavior.
- The `const` data "says": This data is `const`, but, other data of this type may not be, so, at least some amount of "taking away `const`-nes" is OK between variables and pointers of this type. Of course, if someone casts pointer to this data to non-const and it is indeed in read-only memory, we're in trouble.

So, the bottom line is the same, but there is a subtle difference. How the compiler interprets that is really up to the compiler. It may very well be that the `typedef` is very rare (it is in my experience), so the compiler is optimised for the more common case.

Comment: Yes, I found that this is a compiler specific issue. It interprets a constant to be placed in flash(ROM) memory. The real issue here is that in this compiler a `const` appears to be a specifically 'per variable' declaration. It doesn't propagate through a type. So I kind of wasted your time, which I am sorry about. Anyway thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between data definitions declared `const`, and regular `const`ness, in that it becomes undefined behaviour (at least in C++) if you cast away the `const` from an object that was defined with the qualifier.

Outside of language-lawyering, the rationale is obvious: we want these as part of the read-only image, while still permitting both people who know what they are doing to use `const_cast`, because there are [good reasons](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/ad0f282819902a1986256f79005462b1/5ff49186e691a2d8862579b8005f94b8/$FILE/visa.h) for that as well.

In C, we have pretty much the same motivation: put constants into read-only memory, but allow casts to work. When the qualifier is attached to the type, that is not a strong guarantee that the user intended the variable to go to read-only memory, so the compiler may err on the side of caution here.

Answer (score 0):

consts are stored in read only memory - my guess is you are just shifting where the data is.  Hard to say 100% without seeing more information.

Comment: `const`-qualified objects are not necessarily stored in read-only memory. Consider `const int r = rand();`.